# Selenium Chrome WebDriver is opening Setting as default tab asking to reset the setting

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Selenium Chrome WebDriver is opening Setting as default tab asking to reset the setting.

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 15):

I too faced this issue, fixed it by following below steps.

```
Run regedit command using window+r shortcut.

Registry Editor will opens then perform below mentioned.

There is a setting in the registry that's causing it.In the registry it's 
under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\TriggeredReset

Delete the TriggeredReset key and then close regedit.

Let me know if it works for you.
```

Comment: After deleting TriggeredReset chrome browser is opening but url is not getting loaded and facing below error.org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot get automation extension

Comment: @AbhishekRaghuwanshi that is the known issue , please download latest chrome driver version 2.28. This issue fixed in this version.

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Comment: I mentioned url for downloading chrome driver issue will be fixed, let me know if you have any queries

Comment: I have three things I can delete (Default), Timestamp, and ToolName. Which one do I delete?

Answer (score 11):

For macs, I solved this problem by updating chromedriver via `brew upgrade chromedriver`

Comment: Updating chromedriver also helped
in my case I just downloaded it from: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Answer (score 3):

This was an issue with latest Chrome on mac when driving UI with selenium. I installed previous version of chrome (59) on my mac, you can get here - http://google-chrome.en.uptodown.com/mac/old. I also turned off auto-updates by running the following in the command line:

```
defaults write com.google.Keystone.Agent checkInterval 0
```

Comment: Just ran into this with node on mac.  Trying to figure out how to use the version you suggested (59). 
For reference, here's another question regarding the same issue with ruby:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47145296/how-to-stop-chromedriver-from-opening-settings-tab-automatically

Comment: Just replace the Chrome browser in your Applications folder with version 59 provided in the link above. Fixed the issue for me -- thanks Karan.

Answer (score 3):

To deal with this issue please delete `TriggeredReset` entry from Chrome registry as mentioned below:

1. Open a run box by pressing Windows key <kbd>⊞</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>:
2. Type `regedit` and press OK, Registry Editor will open.
3. There is a setting in the registry that's causing it. 
   In the registry it's under: `KEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\TriggeredReset`
4. Delete the `TriggeredReset` folder (the whole folder which contains 3 files) and then close regedit.
5. Try running you test again.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened with Chrome Version 62.0.3202.94, when the browser automatically updated. It was easily fixed when I updated chromedriver in my automation framework.
Just download new version of chromedriver from: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads
and put it to your Drivers folder in your framework.

Answer (score 1):

I have version 62.0.3202.94 and I've tried updating my chrome driver using webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 2.33 but when i run my protractor tests it still keeps opening tabs for chrome:settings/help during the tests even if I keep closing them.

Comment: Hello @Audrey, Welcome to SO, this is not an answer, please take a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Audrey After updating the chromedirver npm package to 2.33.2 the settings issue went away

Answer (score 1):

For some users it's been observed that LEAPWORK opens two browser tabs in Chrome, one of them is the settings and the other tab is the Url specified in Start Web Browser. This issue won't let you proceed until you click CANCEL and Navigate to the Url again. Resetting browser is also not going to help you.

This issue belongs to Chrome browser registry, and it usually occurs when TriggeredReset entry resides in Chrome browser's registry.

**Resolution**

To deal with this issue please delete TriggeredReset entry from Chrome registry as mentioned below:

1.Open a run box by pressing the Windows key + R:

2.Type ‘regedit ’ and press OK, Registry Editor will open.

3.There is a setting in the registry that's causing it. In the registry it's under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\TriggeredReset

4.Delete the TriggeredReset key and then close regedit.
Try running you test again.

Cheers:)

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following steps:

1. Kill all the `chromedriver` instances running in your windows Task Manager.
2. Clean all the projects in Eclipse.
3. Restart your system once.
4. Provide the following options to start your Chrome browser:

   ```
   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

   options.addArguments("test-type");
   options.addArguments("start-maximized");
   options.addArguments("--js-flags=--expose-gc");
   options.addArguments("--enable-precise-memory-info");
   options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
   options.addArguments("--disable-default-apps");
   options.addArguments("test-type=browser");    
   options.addArguments("disable-infobars");

   driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
   ```

Your program should work with latest chrome driver 2.28 & Chrome Version 57.0.2987.110 (32/64-bit).

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Chrome browser is opening but url is not loading.

Comment: Its working fine after updating the driver.Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

try this. it worked when I had the same issue:

1. `npm install selenium-standalone@latest -g`
2. `selenium-standalone install`
3. `selenium-standalone start`

Answer (score 0):

this is best solution

Resolution

To deal with this issue please delete TriggeredReset entry from Chrome registry as mentioned below:

1.Open a run box by pressing the Windows key + R:

2.Type ‘regedit ’ and press OK, Registry Editor will open.

3.There is a setting in the registry that's causing it. In the registry it's under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\TriggeredReset

4.Delete the TriggeredReset key and then close regedit. Try running you test again.

Cheers:)