# How to stop chromedriver from opening settings tab automatically?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, watir

When I run ruby watir script for opening chrome browser, it also opens up another chrome tab with address "chrome://settings/help" and sets focus on that. How can I disable such additional tabs getting created?

Comment: What happens when you manually open Chrome?

Comment: What version of chrome and chromedriver.exe are you running?

Comment: show us your code please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: I updated the chromedriver to **2.33** that the selenium-standalone package uses and the config of the selenium server. The tab is not appearing anymore. You can try to update the chromedriver that your ruby script uses to 2.33.

If you need my Chrome version, it is currently 62.0.3202.89 (64 bit) for Mac OS.

I ran into this issue when I tried to used our selenium automation in nodejs. I tried the new chromedriver 2.33 but the issue persisted. I just downgraded my Chrome to version 59 at the moment until it can be fixed.

Comment: Update: I updated the chromedriver that the selenium-standalone package uses and the config of the selenium server. It is now working properly.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17888598)

Comment: Hi @waka, you're correct. I edited my post to properly show my updated answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed using the latest release: ChromeDriver 2.33. You can pick it from https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

We hit the same after last update of chrome: 62.0.3202.89

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17869748)

Comment: Chad, you are correct. I've edited my answer with the correct content. Thanks

Comment: Seeing the same issue even with latest version of chromedriver, 2.33.2 loaded via npm.  Any suggestions?