# Chrome opening settings/help tab when I attempt to run my wdio tests

Tags: google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io, end-to-end

Found essentially the exact same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47145296/how-to-stop-chromedriver-from-opening-settings-tab-automatically), but none of the answers work for me. Essentially when I try to run my wdio tests, it opens another and focuses on another tab which is at `chrome://settings/help`.

As it is right now, I am running this on MacOS. My Chrome version is 63.0.3239.132 (which as of now is fully up to date).My Chrome Driver is version 2.35.528157, which according to the other thread the bug has been fixed.

The only thing so far that I can do is downgrade the version of chrome, which is not something I wanted. Is there a way to actually solve this problem?

Comment: Just wanted to check and see if you've put any sort of value in your "wdio config" for the 'baseUrl' value? Also are you running any sort of "open" commands in your script?

Comment: @Denzik yes I did. I set it as `http://localhost:8080/.
What do you mean by open commands?

Comment: Pardon me, I meant to ask if you are calling any 'url' commands. This opens or tries to load the url value set as your baseUrl value in the config. I just wanted to see if there was any sort of url calls in your scripts that might otherwise override the baseUrl command value. Just curious as well, what version of your webdriver-io are you running?

Comment: Ahh I see. No, I'm not.
As for the version webdriver-io it is 4.8.0
Thanks!

Comment: Webdriver-IO is now a few more versions ahead of you at the moment. I believe the latest is v. 4.10.1. My thought is is you may need to update your webdriver.io as you appear to be running a newer version of ChromeDriver. Maybe give that a shot?

Comment: I've updated it to v4.10.1 and unfortunately it is still doing the same thing :(

Comment: Okay - Next thought - Which version of the "Selenium Standalone Server" are you running. The latest version from Selenium is 3.8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Had this running chromedriver 2.30
Just make sure you version of chromedriver is up to date. Current is 2.33
if it's automatically installed by selenium-standalone, make sure you update it too.